# How do I fix my string issue?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

```
local background = display.newImage("black.png", 0, 0)

local submit = display.newImage("submit.png")
submit.x = display.contentWidth/2
submit.y = display.contentHeight-100

local nameInstructions = display.newText("Enter your name", 10, 50, native.systemFont, 24)
local usersName = native.newTextField(10, 100, 350, 50)
usersName.inputType = "default"

local function keyboardListener (event)
    native.setKeyboardFocus(nil)
end

background:addEventListener("tap", keyboardListener)

local function reverseName(event)
    reverseUsersName = string.reverse(usersName)
end

submit:addEventListener("tap", reverseName)

local reverse = display.newText(reverseUsersName)
reverse.x = display.contentWidth/2
reverse.y = display.contentHeight/2
```

Every time that I run this using my Corona SDK thing, I get this:

```
Bad argument #-1 to 'newText' (string expected, got nil)

stack traceback:
    [C]: ?
    [C]: in function 'newText'
    ...Corona Projects/Assignment 4.3/main.lua/src/main.lua:24: in main chunk
```

Comment: Why no upvotes or accept on any of answers received? If none useful perhaps a comment why or extend question.

Answer (score 0):

reverseName is in the local function reverseName(event), but this function is called once u press or tap on the submit . But here local reverse = display.newText(reverseUsersName), is called before you tap on the sumbit . That is why its giving you error.

Answer (score 0):

The only place that `reverseUsersName`, accessed on line 24, is set, is *inside* the function `reverseName(event)`. In this function, `reverseUsersName` is a global so *after* the function is run once, that variable will be accessible from other parts of your script, but until then, it does not exist.

Now in line 22 you've registered `reverseName` as event listener for "tap" events, but events are only generated after your script has been executed once (and in between calls to your script callbacks like reverseName and keyboardListener are callbacks), so when you create the display text just after, the variable does not yet exist.

So what you would have to do is update the text of the `reverse` display item in your `reverseName` listener so that every time you click on the button, the reversed name becomes visible. And because of that, you would have to declare your `reverse` variable *above* `reverseName` function so that it is available as an upvalue (read the Corona getting started docs, they are excellent and discuss this subtlety) in that function. And presumably you would want to initialize with showing the usersName rather than reverse.

So you would need something like

```
local reverse = display.newText(usersName)

local function reverseName(event)
    reverseUsersName = string.reverse(usersName)
    reverse.SetText(reverseUserName)
end

submit:addEventListener("tap", reverseName)
```

Note that if you want the string *being displayed* to be reversed every time you press tap, rather than only first time you press it, you will have to use

```
local function reverseName(event)
    reverseUsersName = string.reverse(reverseUsersName)
    reverse.SetText(reverseUserName)
end

reverseUsersName = usersName
```

Comment: Whoever -1 could you follow SO guideline of putting comment explaining why it is detrimental so author can fix (if just not helpful you don't upvote but you don't downvote you let upvotes take care of showing which answer is most helpful).

Comment: Both Yours and krs's answers appears to be correct. Why downvoted!!!. +1 from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Check your function `reverseName` and the text object(`reverse`) with the following code:

```
local reverse --[[ Initialize the object with a global scope,
                   so you can access it anywhere from the page. --]]
local function reverseName(event)
  --[[ In the below line, usersName is a table value. It is the reason 
         of the error. For getting the string from the text field, you 
         have to provide 'usersName.text' --]]
  reverseUsersName = string.reverse(usersName.text) 
  reverse.text = reverseUsersName -- Assign the text field value to your text object
end

submit:addEventListener("tap", reverseName)

reverse = display.newText("",20,20,nil,20) --see the parameters of display.newText()*
reverse.x = display.contentWidth/2
reverse.y = display.contentHeight/2
```

*Corona API: [display.newText()](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newText.html)